# Declaring a function that return a 2D array in a header file?

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration, header-files

I am trying to declare, within my header file, a function that returns a 2D array.  How can this be accomplished, given that we already know the size of the array?  Below is what I'm currently doing.

```
class Sample
{
public:
    char[x][y] getArr();
    void blah(int x, int y);
private:
    const static int x = 8;
    const static int y = 2;
    char arr[x][y];
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns-out my original answer was totally incorrect, but [I can't delete it since it's been accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances). From [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636144/declaring-a-function-that-return-a-2d-array-in-a-header-file/4636331#4636331) separate [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636144/declaring-a-function-that-return-a-2d-array-in-a-header-file/4636361#4636361) below, I was able to compile this:

```
class Sample
{
    const static int x = 8;
    const static int y = 2;
public:
    typedef char SampleArray[x][y];

    SampleArray& getArr();
    void blah(int x, int y);

private:
    SampleArray arr;
};

Sample::SampleArray& Sample::getArr ()
{
    return arr;
}
```

(I had compiled my original solution only with the OP's given class declaration, not the definition of `getArr()`.)

<s>Just return a pointer to a pointer.</s>

```
char** getArr();
```

Comment: @Fred and @Johannes Ugh, thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the answer and converted it to community wiki.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use a typedef.

```
    typedef char TArray[2][2];
    TArray& getArr();
```

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are not first-class citizens in C++. Please use `boost::array` (or `std::array` in C++0x) instead. It will behave much more like you want it to behave.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, an array itself cannot be returned from a function directly.
Alternatively, you can return a reference to an array, or a pointer to an array.
So, you can write as:

```
char (&getArr())[x][y] { return arr; }
```

or

```
char (*getArr())[x][y] { return &arr; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use a [typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636144/declaring-a-function-that-return-a-2d-array-in-a-header-file/4636331#4636331).

Answer (score -1):

Yup, a pointer to a pointer is the way to go. It's really hard to think about. I recommend you do a memory map on a piece of paper just to understand the concept. When I was taking C++ classes I decided I wanted functionality just like you are suggesting, after a lot of time, I drew a map of all the memory I needed and it dawned on me I was looking at a pointer to a pointer. That blew me away.

Comment: While it may make the most sense to return the array data member given, this question is vaguely worded: all these downvotes are unwarranted.  This is still good advice in general, even if I disagree with emphasis on manual memory management.